# Recurring select gem failing after Rails 5 update with undefined method `select_recurring'

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

[Recurring_select](https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select) gem started failing after Rails 5 update with this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `select_recurring' for #<#<Class>
Did you mean?  select_second):
    40:     .form-group
    41:       = f.label :schedule, :class=>"col-sm-5 control-label"
    42:       %div.col-sm-5
    43:         = f.select_recurring :current_custom_rule,  []
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. I have fixed it in my pull request:  https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select/pull/115

Basically the gem is currently supporting only Rails 3 and Rails 4, i just added a simple conditional to make it support Rails 5 also with same functionality as Rails 4.

You can use my forked branch till the time it gets accepted by adding this to your gemfile:

```
gem 'recurring_select',  git: 'https://github.com/sahild/recurring_select.git', branch: 'master'
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Can you also please add a edit to this post when your pull request gets accepted so that I can use this gem from rubygems